# Can it call the js file from another server in JavaScript option runat="server"?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, runatserver, runat

Is it possible to use next exsample?

In A.asp of [A server],
to use runat="server" src="[B server]/js/script.js"

I would like to use javascript imported from other server in asp code

Comment: javascript loaded in a script tag can come from anywhere, don't use `runat` on a script tag - oh, wait, you want to use javascript on the server side?? What is the server side language, if it's not javascript you're SOOL

Comment: what you are trying to ask doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: Wait a minute, are you trying to do what nodejs does? may be?

Comment: I want to use common js files of another server in asp code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

runat="server" converts the asp part to standard HTML and then sends it across to the browser. So that is not something you can do. But if you want to use javascript from a different server, look into [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)